# Mysql's MD5 not playing well with encodings

Tags: mysql, encryption, encoding, md5

I ran into an interesting problem today. In my user table all fields are latin1_swedish_ci. Passwords are stored as a md5 hash of a user specific salt and their password.

This query results in error:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE email = '...' 
AND password = MD5('1234' + salt)
```

complaining about a `#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='`

When I change the last line to:

```
AND password = CAST(MD5('1234' + salt) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1)
```

the query performs just fine.

First I doubted that my input, here '1234', might be confusing the charsets, but I tried simple test selects with only a md5 of `salt` and no other input, and still the character encoding error remained.

I suppose casting the md5 as latin1 for comparing is one option, another maybe to set the password column to utf8_general_ci. My question however is this:

Why? Why does the md5 return something that seems to be utf8 even if the parts you feed it are in a different encoding?

Comment: You should probably stop using this password scheme. MD5 has been broken for many years now. Take a look at [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Comment: Would mysql's `ENCRYPT` or `SHA1` be a considerable improvement, in your opinion? `SHA2` isn't available on the server, and php is outdated, too, I fear. I tried adding the user specific salt to improve, but if there is viable alternatives to `MD5` I would use them, too.

Comment: bcrypt is what you should be using. Take a look at [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords). I'm don't know how ENCRYPT works, but I do know that SHA1 is also broken. Simple hashing algorithms like that are not recommended _in general_ anymore. I highly recommend that you take a look at bcrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html):

> Some encryption functions return strings of ASCII characters: MD5(), OLD_PASSWORD(), PASSWORD(), SHA(), SHA1(). As of MySQL 5.5.3, their return value is a nonbinary string that has a character set and collation determined by the character_set_connection and collation_connection system variables. Before 5.5.3, these functions return binary strings. The same change was made for SHA2() in MySQL 5.5.6.

In addition to the things you already mention you could change the column definition. Do you really want your password hashes to be sorted and compared according to rules used in Swedish? Perhaps `binary` or `varbinary` would be better column types.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for pointing the section out. I checked the MD5 reference on that page, but not the introduction..! As for the encoding, I understood that the encoding of the hash doesn't matter, if only there is consistency.